# How much can I hang from a blinds bracket?

Tags: drywall, windows, blinds

Naughty question--I'm renting right now in a gorgeous, modern apartment and obviously can't hang anything on the walls. Buuuut.. I have this 65cm diameter mirror, approximately 4-5kg (something like that), which I would love to hang. I found a potential place and method to hang it, but I wanted to ask the experts here about it first.

I have two windows, about 150cm apart, both with blinds, and I figured that maybe if I thread some fishing line on the inside brackets for the blinds to connect to the upper corners of the mirror, I could potentially support it between the two blinds. From what I see from the brackets, they are screwed into the window frame using regular metal screws. I pulled on the brackets pretty hard to test how strong they are and they seem fairly steadfast, with no wriggling or looseness, though I wouldn't want to swing on them with my whole body weight or anything.

So, is this an idea that might work, or is it utterly dreadful and will end in catastrophe?

Comment: Fishing line?? Be aware that a 5kg mirror hanging on a horizontal line imparts _much_ more than 5kg of force upon the line. This will fail in grand fashion unless your idea of fishing involves harpoons.

Comment: Perhaps a metal rod or wooden slat (painted white) could be placed on top of brackets.   Then you could hang the mirror from that.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I would be very hesitant to employ that idea. That sounds like a catastrophe waiting to happen. And if your landlord has to come into your apartment and sees what you did s/he might not be happy with your idea at all.

Is it stipulated in your lease that you can't hang anything on the walls? I've lived in many areas and in several states. And from my experience, as long as I fill in any holes and leave the apartment the way it was when I first moved I have never had any problems.

Mirrors are heavy glass. I would want to support eleven pounds on the wall with something that goes into a stud. But if the drywall is in excellent shape this should suffice:

[Picture hanger](https://www.target.com/p/arrow75-lb-picture-hanger-4pk/-/A-13347459?sid=1205S&ref=tgt_adv_XS000000&AFID=google_pla_df&CPNG=PLA_Home%20Improvement%20Shopping_Local&adgroup=SC_Home%20Improvement&LID=700000001170770pgs&network=g&device=c&location=9061300&gclid=CjwKCAiAqIHTBRAVEiwA6TgJw5oRhMdMP3M2X1LGTus_9vcn88ewvegALGDwxDpeZ8d9V1hG_crAgxoClYgQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

That has a 75lb weight load capacity. It's just one small nail head that could be filled with toothpaste once you remove it and move away.

I would be surprised if you can't hang anything on your walls. I don't think I would rent an apartment that prohibited me from hanging a small mirror on the wall. Perhaps call your landlord and ask. Maybe s/he will feel better doing her/himself. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! In Australia, the renting culture is a wee bit different, you cannot put anything into the walls whatsoever or modify the apartment whatsoever. You have to go through the building manager and the property group. It's a bit complicated. Even those stick-on removable hooks are discouraged because they could rip paint up or leave stains. Come to think of it, I'm not even sure if it is drywall, it could be anything from concrete to plasterboard, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Perhaps you could put a small table or desk in that location, maybe with a small shelf that sits on top, and put the mirror on the furniture.  Have you looked at gorilla hooks?

Comment: My apologies, I thought you were in the U.S. Good luck on making your project work!